# What kind of snake is this

Tags: species-identification, species, herpetology

Found this outside on patio in northern Virginia, Ashburn area, September 2018. It's about 12 inches. Is it a water snake or rattlesnake?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It looks like an [Eastern Hognose Snake](http://www.virginiaherpetologicalsociety.com/reptiles/snakes/eastern-hog-nosed-snake/eastern_hognose_snake.php), which is characterized by an upturned nose and high likelihood of playing dead.

These are described as variable in coloration:

> "Two color phases are common in Virginia: (1) a patterned phase (79.6%, n = 98), characterized by a series of 19-27 (average = 23.2 ± 2.4, n = 12) black or dark-brown blotches along middorsal line, with alternating black spots on sides; body color consists of varying combinations of gray, tan, pink, yellow, orange, and red; venter of body and tail immaculate cream to dark gray;"

If you replace the tan in this image (www.virginiaherpetologicalsociety.com) with gray in yours, I think the pattern match and overall body form are very similar:

[image: hognose snake]

Comment: Another characteristic of Hognoses is their tendency to flatten their necks in a cobra-like fashion when they feel threatened. This is visible on both the picture in the question, and in the answer.